# Counting the number of rows in an HTML table except don't count the <th></th> as a row

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, rows

I need your help,

if the following code below counts every table row in a table, how can it be amended such that the code won't count the `<th></th>` as a row itself?

```
var rows = document.getElementById("data").rows.length;
```

Comment: Does your table use `thead/tbody`?

Comment: post your HTML so we can help, please.

Comment: no <thead> or <tbody> just uses <table><tr><th></th><tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using thead and tbody

HTML:

```
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Hz</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("data").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows.length;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MqdK/)

Comment: He doesn't have tbody

Comment: Well maybe the OP should spend 30 seconds and add one. :)

Comment: I will add one, it seems like the easiest option. I will accept this answer in 5 mins. Thanks so much.

Comment: It will fail for this markup:
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><th></th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I do not think that is what the OP was worried about.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MqdK/1/), the code I tried is:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{    
    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName('th').length == 0)
        count++;
}
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your HTML markup you have to count the correct rows yourself:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("data").rows
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].cells[0].tagName != 'TH') count++
}
console.log(count)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cHW6z/

Comment: It will fail for this markup: <table> <tbody> <tr><td></td><th></th></tr> </tbody> </table>

Answer (score 0):

With the love of jQuery, if you don't want to do it with pure JS:

```
$('#tableId tr').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).find('th').size() == 0;
}).size();
```