# Output Number of cells and rows of a table

Tags: javascript, dom, rows, cells

I have a problem with the output of the number of cells and rows of a table.

I've wrote the following code:

```
function outputValue () {    
var table =document.getElementById('table1');    
var x =table.getElementById('table1').rows.length;    
var y =getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells.length;    
var text = document.createTextNode(' Dimension :' +x+ 'x' + y);    
x.y.appendChild(text);    
var output =document.getElementById('outputValue');    
output.appendChild(text);}
```

I was able to make a table that can automatically change the number of cells and rows. The next stage would be to print out in a `<p>`-tag the dimensions of the cells and rows, so you can see how many cells and rows it contains.

I don't have enough experience in programming, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The [*rows*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) and *cells* collections are live, they will update as rows and cells are added to the table. Note that not every row must contain the same number of cells.

Comment: `var x =table.getElementById('table1').rows.length; ` - `table` is already a reference to the table, calling `getElementById` on it again i nonsense (and should throw an error in the browser console as well, so make sure you always check there first!) `x.y.appendChild(text);` - this makes even less sense. Both `x` and `y` contain numbers, integer values. `x` has no property `y`, and neither does make trying to append a text node to a number make any sense either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501568

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.